# Passing a URL variable to category.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to pass a URL variable to my *category.php* file.
Currently my category page is at `http://example.com/category-slug/`
I am using the SEO plugin to rewrite `http://example.com/category/category-slug` and remove the **`/category/`** part.

Also, the settings formy permalinks are set to this option in the settings menu: `http://example.com/sample-post/`

Now I need to be able to pass a variable in the URL like:

```
http://example.com/category-slug/?type=VALUE
```

or

```
http://example.com/category-slug/VALUE
```

where "type" is the name of the variable and VALUE is its value

I have tried using this piece of code in my *functions.php* file:

```
<?php    
   add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars' );
   function parameter_queryvars( $qvars )
     {
        $qvars[] = 'type';
        return $qvars;
     }
    global $wp_query;
     if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['type']))
      {
        print $wp_query->query_vars['type'];
      }
?>
```

However, when I try to open `http://example.com/category-slug/?type=something` or `http://example.com/category-slug/something` I get "nothing found" and "Page not found" pages.

While I see this has been discussed over and over, none of the solutions seem to work for my case.
How do I properly pass a variable to a category page?

Comment: have you seen:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/passing-variables-using-the-permalink-structure

Comment: This only seems to work when in a 'page' or 'post'. When in a category it interprets the variable as a category name (I think) and does not even open the page.

Comment: well i think this will hellp:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104927/using-url-parameters-list-posts-from-category-and-custom-taxonomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you code will never reach the if statement, as you *return* from the function before.

I also don't know which SEO tool you are using, but there is one function that goes with the "query_vars" filter: [add_rewrite_rule()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

I would recommend to write a little plugin which does the rewriting of the category permalink. Something like this (untested, but similar to a plugin I use):

```
// Flush added rewrite rules on activation
function category_permalink_rewrite_activate() {
    category_permalink_rewrite_set_rewrite_rules();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'category_permalink_rewrite_activate' );

// Remove rewrite rule for event archives
function category_permalink_rewrite_deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules(); 
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'category_permalink_rewrite_deactivate' );

// Add rewrite rule for category permalink on init
    add_rewrite_rule( '^category-(.*)/(.*)', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&type=$matches[2]', 'top' );
kaufunction category_permalink_rewrite_set_rewrite_rules() {
}
add_filter( 'init', 'category_permalink_rewrite_set_rewrite_rules' );

// Register the custom query var so WP recognizes it
function category_permalink_rewrite_add_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'type';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'category_permalink_rewrite_add_query_vars' );
```

Comment: I set up the website by using a workaround. I have not tested this solution yet, but since its the only one and based on a working plugin, I'm marking it as the correct answer.